# How to perform fast search in firebase in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I want to add search functionality in my app and I am using Firebase
And I am new to Firebase so,

**I Have RecyclerView where I want show the search results according to user input**

how can I Do that?

**Well I am using firestore but I will use the one which has more fast search**

Comment: Are you using Firebase realtime database or Firestore? If you are referring to full text  search then you would have to use some 3rd party service such as Algolia. There's a Firebase [extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-algolia-search) for Algolia.

Comment: Well I am using firestore but I will use the one which has more fast search

Comment: Firestore has no native full text search or similar feature built-in so you can use the extension mentioned in my first comment to index your documents in Algolia and then use [Algolia Android Client](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/getting-started/install/android/?client=android) to search documents from it.

Comment: how can I do that can you please give me some hint or sinppets

Comment: Sure, let me post an explanation for that

Answer (score 1):

Firestore has no native full text search feature so you would have to use a dedicated third-party search service such a Algolia, ElasticSearch, etc. However, there's a [Firebase extension for Algolia](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-algolia-search) which will index your documents in Algolia immediately after they are added to Firestore. Behind the scenes this extension uses [Firestore Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) for Cloud functions which runs a function when a new document is added.

To install the extension, click on extensions tab in your Firebase console and search for that extension (or visit [this page](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-algolia-search)) and click `Install`. Go through the configuration process where you'll need to enter collection which you want to index and some Algolia API keys. Once installed, it should add all new documents from your configured collection to Algolia.

To fetch the docs from Algolia in your Android App, first install Algolia's [Android Client](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/getting-started/install/android/?client=android) by adding the following dependency:

```
dependencies {
    // [...]
    implementation 'com.algolia:algoliasearch-android:3.+'
    // This will automatically update to the latest v3 release when you build your project
}
```

Then initialize the SDK as follows:

```java
Client client = new Client("AlgoliaAppKey", "AdminAPIKey");
Index index = client.getIndex("your_index_name");

// your_index_name is specified by your while configuring the extension
```

Then to search documents in a specific index, you can use the Algolia client like this:

```java
Index index = client.getIndex("your_index_name");
Query query = new Query("query string that you want to search")
  .setAttributesToRetrieve("firstname", "lastname")
  .setHitsPerPage(50);
index.searchAsync(query, new CompletionHandler() {
  @Override
  public void requestCompleted(JSONObject content, AlgoliaException error) {
    // [...]
    // Add content to your RecyclerView 
  }
});
```

To search through multiple indices and running facet search, you can refer Algolia's [documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/methods/search/) for some examples.